# Failed Latex Upload in arXiv

Tags: compiling, arxiv

I am facing some difficulties in finding the errors causing the arXiv rejections of my LaTeX file. 
Could you please help me in fixing them? 
I would like  to point out that I am using a file called `mysymbol.sty`  so to abbreviate some command and write for instance `\bb` instead of `\mathbf` (don't know if it can cause problems).

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2016 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <productgraph.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <multidimensionalgs.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <dog.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <IEEEbib.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <featuregraph.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <avg_error_extended2.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <mysymbol.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <dog.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <spconf.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <avg_error_extended2.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <Template.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'Template.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3135411/ && pdflatex 'Template.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Template.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./spconf.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/empheq.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/balance.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(./mysymbol.sty) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
No file Template.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsptm.fd)


[1{/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `moura' on page 2 undefined on input line 97.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.101 ...h_{k}\bbS^{k}\bbx_t := \mathbf{H}(\marhbf
{\bbS})\bbx_{t},
?
! Emergency stop.
l.101 ...h_{k}\bbS^{k}\bbx_t := \mathbf{H}(\marhbf
{\bbS})\bbx_{t},
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Template.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'Template.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'Template.aux' (1587115435 >= 1587115435)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'Template.out' (1587115435 >= 1587115435)
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3135411/ && pdflatex 'Template.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Template.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./spconf.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/empheq.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/balance.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(./mysymbol.sty)
No file Template.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsptm.fd)


[1{/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `moura' on page 2 undefined on input line 96.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.100 ...h_{k}\bbS^{k}\bbx_t := \mathbf{H}(\marhbf
{\bbS})\bbx_{t},
?
! Emergency stop.
l.100 ...h_{k}\bbS^{k}\bbx_t := \mathbf{H}(\marhbf
{\bbS})\bbx_{t},
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Template.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'Template.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'Template.aux' (1587115435 >= 1587115435)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3135411/ && tex 'Template.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./Template.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \pdfoutput
=1
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \pdfoutput
=1
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Template.log.

[verbose]: tex 'Template.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3135411/ && tex 'Template.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./Template.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \pdfoutput
=1
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \pdfoutput
=1
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Template.log.

[verbose]: tex 'Template.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'Template.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is at line 101 as stated by the log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.101 ...h_{k}\bbS^{k}\bbx_t := \mathbf{H}(\marhbf
{\bbS})\bbx_{t},
```

If I read right, you should write, instead:

```
h_{k}\bbS^{k}\bbx_t := \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{\bbS})\bbx_{t}
```

You had a typo in `\mathbf`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem. It was an oversight.

Comment: A lot can be learned from log files! ;)